# Can I hide the purchase button?

Tags: paypal

I'm using PayPal's SDK to display a purchase button. However, two buttons are displayed and the button at the bottom is unnecessary and may confuse users. I want to hide it if possible, but is there such an option?

[image]

Comment: Use `style="display: none;"`?

Comment: if this is the regular paypal SDK, which injects an iframe: you can't, because for very good security reasons you're not allowed to reach into someone else's iframe. If you want a possibly better answer, you'll have to show how you're actually using the paypal SDK (the calls you're using, not your private keys etc, of course)

Comment: I have no choice but to make my own API.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the black button? You certainly can, but it serves a purpose: that button will expand a credit card form in locales where it's available, so it is useful to have unless you are displaying this in a spot where only "PayPal" should appear.

Here are options for hiding funding sources: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#disable-funding

If you are pressed for space, you might also want to switch to an `horizontal` layout style so that options like PP Credit or Venmo are automatically presented side-by-side, when applicable to that particular buyer: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/customize-button/#layout

For an interactive demo of how the button works in different countries, you can go here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client and append e.g. `&buyer-country=JP&locale=ja_JP` or `&buyer-country=US&locale=en_US` , and so on, to the `script` tag.

(The buyer-country parameter only works in sandbox mode; for live mode their country is detected automatically.)